# Scrollbar auto hide on overflow does not work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a basic layout with the header fixed on the top and a main content area which has the contents and a sidebar. The sidebar always sticks to the left and the layout works in such a way that the content-area and the sidebar scroll independently. I have set `overflow-y:auto` so that the scrollbar appears whenever the content overflows. I am facing the following issues:

1. The scrollbars do not auto hide. Ideally in most of the browsers, the scrollbar hides when the mouse is not over the div even if the content is overflowing. (For eg: http://materializecss.com/. If you expand the menu items on the sidebar and move the mouse away from the sidebar, the scrollbar hides)
2. There are 3 scrollbars on the screen. If the sidebar content does not overflow, the scrollbar on the very right (the complete page scrollbar) takes over and moves the sidebar content under the header. I do not want that to happen. The sidebar content should never go under the header.

What am I doing incorrectly? Could you please help?

```css
header {
  background: pink;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.main .content-area {
  flex: 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
.main .sidenav {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  order: -1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-nav">
  Header
</header>
<main class="main">
  <div class="content-area">
    Content Area.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ludus voluptaria intellegebat has an, vis movet sententiae te. Ex iisque referrentur vis, mei id dolorum erroribus. Eros erant at pri. Nam eu falli nostrum invenire, quo mundi feugait complectitur ei. Nec elitr soleat ea, quo in tantas percipit corrumpit.

Duo graecis facilisi partiendo id, commune omnesque cu his, at vim tacimates interpretaris. Ut oporteat quaestio sea. Eos eu lorem tation perpetua, nec et solum senserit. Ei diceret delenit suscipit per. Inani labore no qui.

Eos wisi altera id. Possim sensibus est et, at oblique sanctus adolescens eos. Wisi commodo est cu. Regione patrioque percipitur vim eu, facer vocent vituperatoribus pri cu. Delenit similique his ei, ne eros scripta accusata cum, meis quaerendum vituperatoribus vis no. No elitr facilisi corrumpit his.

Eos ut semper reprimique consequuntur, mea cu percipit efficiendi. No possit graeco noluisse ius, ea quis justo facer vix, pri cibo verear fuisset id. Omittam liberavisse pro id, expetenda conclusionemque pro ut. Ludus forensibus eu vis, mundi moderatius ad qui. Expetenda accusamus vis an, an feugiat invenire recteque vim. Ceteros adipiscing adversarium ne usu.

Sale deleniti ad pri, no eos reque voluptua. Debet verterem eu vix, percipit posidonium ut nec. Ad aperiam repudiandae mei, sed no utroque fastidii, facilisi forensibus sit id. Case nonumy ne nec, vide vulputate adipiscing sed ex, pro solum facer maiorum in. Te exerci scripta electram vim, melius vocibus honestatis ne pro. Atqui adversarium pri ut
.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ludus voluptaria intellegebat has an, vis movet sententiae te. Ex iisque referrentur vis, mei id dolorum erroribus. Eros erant at pri. Nam eu falli nostrum invenire, quo mundi feugait complectitur ei. Nec elitr soleat ea, quo in tantas percipit corrumpit.

Duo graecis facilisi partiendo id, commune omnesque cu his, at vim tacimates interpretaris. Ut oporteat quaestio sea. Eos eu lorem tation perpetua, nec et solum senserit. Ei diceret delenit suscipit per. Inani labore no qui.

Eos wisi altera id. Possim sensibus est et, at oblique sanctus adolescens eos. Wisi commodo est cu. Regione patrioque percipitur vim eu, facer vocent vituperatoribus pri cu. Delenit similique his ei, ne eros scripta accusata cum, meis quaerendum vituperatoribus vis no. No elitr facilisi corrumpit his.

Eos ut semper reprimique consequuntur, mea cu percipit efficiendi. No possit graeco noluisse ius, ea quis justo facer vix, pri cibo verear fuisset id. Omittam liberavisse pro id, expetenda conclusionemque pro ut. Ludus forensibus eu vis, mundi moderatius ad qui. Expetenda accusamus vis an, an feugiat invenire recteque vim. Ceteros adipiscing adversarium ne usu.

Sale deleniti ad pri, no eos reque voluptua. Debet verterem eu vix, percipit posidonium ut nec. Ad aperiam repudiandae mei, sed no utroque fastidii, facilisi forensibus sit id. Case nonumy ne nec, vide vulputate adipiscing sed ex, pro solum facer maiorum in. Te exerci scripta electram vim, melius vocibus honestatis ne pro. Atqui adversarium pri ut.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ludus voluptaria intellegebat has an, vis movet sententiae te. Ex iisque referrentur vis, mei id dolorum erroribus. Eros erant at pri. Nam eu falli nostrum invenire, quo mundi feugait complectitur ei. Nec elitr soleat ea, quo in tantas percipit corrumpit.

Duo graecis facilisi partiendo id, commune omnesque cu his, at vim tacimates interpretaris. Ut oporteat quaestio sea. Eos eu lorem tation perpetua, nec et solum senserit. Ei diceret delenit suscipit per. Inani labore no qui.

Eos wisi altera id. Possim sensibus est et, at oblique sanctus adolescens eos. Wisi commodo est cu. Regione patrioque percipitur vim eu, facer vocent vituperatoribus pri cu. Delenit similique his ei, ne eros scripta accusata cum, meis quaerendum vituperatoribus vis no. No elitr facilisi corrumpit his.

Eos ut semper reprimique consequuntur, mea cu percipit efficiendi. No possit graeco noluisse ius, ea quis justo facer vix, pri cibo verear fuisset id. Omittam liberavisse pro id, expetenda conclusionemque pro ut. Ludus forensibus eu vis, mundi moderatius ad qui. Expetenda accusamus vis an, an feugiat invenire recteque vim. Ceteros adipiscing adversarium ne usu.

Sale deleniti ad pri, no eos reque voluptua. Debet verterem eu vix, percipit posidonium ut nec. Ad aperiam repudiandae mei, sed no utroque fastidii, facilisi forensibus sit id. Case nonumy ne nec, vide vulputate adipiscing sed ex, pro solum facer maiorum in. Te exerci scripta electram vim, melius vocibus honestatis ne pro. Atqui adversarium pri ut.
  </div>
  <nav class="sidenav">
    <ul>
      <li><a>1</a></li>
      <li><a>2</a></li>
      <li><a>3</a></li>
      <li><a>4</a></li>
      <li><a>5</a></li>
      <li><a>6</a></li>
      <li><a>1</a></li>
      <li><a>2</a></li>
      <li><a>3</a></li>
      <li><a>4</a></li>
      <li><a>5</a></li>
      <li><a>6</a></li>
      <li><a>1</a></li>
      <li><a>2</a></li>
      <li><a>3</a></li>
      <li><a>4</a></li>
      <li><a>5</a></li>
      <li><a>6</a></li>
      <li><a>1</a></li>
      <li><a>2</a></li>
      <li><a>3</a></li>
      <li><a>4</a></li>
      <li><a>5</a></li>
      <li><a>6</a></li>
      <li><a>1</a></li>
      <li><a>2</a></li>
      <li><a>3</a></li>
      <li><a>4</a></li>
      <li><a>5</a></li>
      <li><a>6</a></li>
      <li><a>1</a></li>
      <li><a>2</a></li>
      <li><a>3</a></li>
      <li><a>4</a></li>
      <li><a>5</a></li>
      <li><a>6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Comment: Would setting the overflow to auto in a selector using the :hover pseudo class give you the intended result, and just make sure you're hiding all overflows in the main selector?  At least for your first problem, that is.

Comment: Like the sidenav here: https://jsfiddle.net/y7d6ev42/

Comment: this works @DanOrlovsky! please add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Shepherds answer is more complete.  I was having problems "fixing" the left column, which is why I was reluctant to make it an answer.  Thank you for first dibs, but I think Shepherds is more deserving.

Comment: Shepherds solution is very helpful but it doesnt work completely in my case. I would like to mark this as the answer. Let me know if you can add it below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the site that you linked to, only the nav scroll bar disappears when you don't hover over it. Not the main content. Sometimes it's good to keep the scroll bar on the main content so people kind of know where they are at on a site.

Anyways... To make the scroll bar disappear when your mouse isn't in the div, add this css:

```
.scrollbox {
  width: 10em;
  height: 50x;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.scrollbox-content,
.scrollbox:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

I also added a max height for your nav, so when it gets too tall, the scroll wheel appears.

```
.main .sidenav {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  order: -1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  height:300px; /* <-- Change to what height you want the scroll wheel to appear */
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GeeShepherd/bLLfxrse/7/

EDIT:

Here's an updated fiddle where your side nav won't go under the header: https://jsfiddle.net/GeeShepherd/e39d184b/7/

I made the side nav fixed and the main content absolute. The height of the side nav is 100% now and takes up 20% of the screen while the main content will take up 80%.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shepherd for your response. It works but partially. The sidebar in your fiddle still goes under the header. I will upvote your answer but I tried what Dan Orlovsky mentioned in the comments above and that completely solve my issue. I also checked the materializecss.com website and they follow the same method. I am going to use that itself. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post to include another fiddle where the side nav won't go under the heading: https://jsfiddle.net/GeeShepherd/e39d184b/7/